# Combining data from two Pandas dataframes with different axes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have one dataframe where the columns contain monthly data:

| ID | Jan | Feb | Mar | so on... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | valJ1 | valF1 | valM1 | ... |
| 2 | valJ2 | valF2 | valM2 | ... |

and another dataframe where the month is given in a column (where 1 = January, 2 = March, ...):

| Month | ID | data1 | data2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | num | num |
| 2 | 1 | num | num |
| 3 | 1 | num | num |
| 4 | 1 | num | num |
| 1 | 2 | num | num |
| 2 | 2 | num | num |
| 3 | 2 | num | num |
| 4 | 2 | num | num |

How can I write a function to combine this data such that:

| Month | ID | data1 | data2 | DF1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | num | num | valJ1 |
| 2 | 1 | num | num | valF1 |
| 3 | 1 | num | num | valM1 |
| 4 | 1 | num | num | valA1 |
| 1 | 2 | num | num | valJ2 |
| 2 | 3 | num | num | valF2 |
| 3 | 2 | num | num | valM2 |
| 4 | 2 | num | num | valA2 |

I've applied for one dataframe but I'm not sure how to combine 2

```
months = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr',...]

def fun(df2,months):
    if df2['Month'] == 1:
        val = df1[months[0]]
    if df2['Month'] == 2:
        val = df1[months[1]]
    #and so on
    return val

df2['DF1'] = pd.DataFrame(df2.apply(fun, axis=1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `melt` to transpose your first dataframe into the shape of the second one the `merge` them. Before you just need a dictionary to map a month number to the abbreviated month name:

```
months = dict(zip(range(1, 4), ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']))

out = pd.merge(df2.assign(Month=df2['Month'].map(months)),
               df1.melt(id_vars='ID', var_name='Month', value_name='DF1'), 
               on=['Month', 'ID'])
```

Output:

```
>>> out
  Month  ID data1 data2    DF1
0   Jan   1   num   num  valJ1
1   Feb   1   num   num  valF1
2   Mar   1   num   num  valM1
3   Jan   2   num   num  valJ2
4   Feb   2   num   num  valF2
5   Mar   2   num   num  valM2
```